# Is the expansion of the Universe absolute, or can it be relative?

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, black-holes, space-expansion, equivalence-principle

Can the free fall conditions of an observer immersed in an intense gravitational field (for example) change the results of his measurements made about the expansion of the universe?

An observer in free fall near the event horizon of a massive black hole, never realizes that he is "falling", but always he sees relatively, that all objects near, or far from him (but in free fall too), move away as if the cause of this phenomenon were his universe in expansion. In part, this is justified because that same observer cannot see those objects that fall towards him, but that are located in the
opposite side of the black hole.

The relative observation indicated above must be identical to the one that allows us on Earth to say that the
universe is expanding?

Should the measurements and rates of the expansion of the universe made by the fictional observer always be identical to those obtained here on Earth?

Comment: I don't think someone in the horizon will see an isotropic expansion. But I might be wrong.

Comment: But I am sure he could find a physics theory that explains why everybody else in the universe sees the same as him (which he assumes after a short lived center-of-the-universe stage). I am sure is not going to be GR.